# Stop/Prohibit Resource monitor from resolving DNS names

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've got this windows 2008 server in production, which happily shows me a lot of data with the Resource Monitor. In particular, I'm monitoring the connections to the server, and it shows the IP address/DNS name and the different settings.

What's happening is that it's being too helpful and resolving the IP's to nice DNS names. What I'd really like is to have it not resolve the IP addresses to DNS Names, since IP's are a lot more handy to work with in this case.

Anyone know what I can do to accomplish this? (Maybe make a rule in the firewall for outbound DNS requests from this app, to be blocked?)

Thanks!

Comment: Sabotaging DNS is generally a bad idea and likely to break many things you wouldn't have expected it to. It will help if you explain the context in which you would prefer to deal with the raw IP addresses, and what applications are involved in processing it (if any).

Comment: Hi, actually, I don't want to block the DNS completely from the server, but rather have the currently connected IP's shown in Resource Monitor not to resolve to from IP's to the long DNS names. (Resulting in a manual DNS to IP conversion for me...)

Comment: I've also tried the windows firewall rule blocking Resource Monitor & Performance monitor's DNS requests, but it doesn't seem to work. (I'm assuming that they are not sending the DNS requests out, but rather handing/requesting them from the DNS service...)